Fantasy movie with ninjas showing up near the end
I have a vague memory of this movie from, I wanna say, the mid 2000s to early 2010s. It was a fantasy movie, like fairy tale fantasy. It was very colorful and silly, so I'm pretty sure it was some sort of parody, or at least it didn't take itself seriously. At the tail end of the movie, ninjas suddenly show up and, a minute later, red ninjas appear as well. I think the movie then ended with a dance scene, but I might be mistaken.

Don't forget to mention if you've asked the questions elsewhere; https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthemoviecalled/comments/1dhoae4/fantasy_movie_with_sudden_ninjas/ and what you've already ruled out.

I can't help thinking of 2010s Bunraku for some reason although I can't think of a single reason why, nothing matches up.

This is reminding me a little of The Poke of Zorro from that episode of The SImpsons! I can't be the only one who wishes they'd made a full length film out of that.

Interesting, interesting… now [lowers therapist glasses] are you sure this wasn’t a fever dream? No? Maybe a hallucination?

This is Ella Enchanted.  The Red Guard are called in by the main villain near the end of the film and they're essentially medieval ninjas.
IMDB has a picture of them
